# nodejs axios on ubuntu cant make request

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, axios

My axios script errors with "ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" when im running it on ubuntu but works fine on my local machine.

```
async function dUAM() {
const data ={
    value: "essentially_off",
  }
axios.patch('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/a065829589b2cd26353e0cdcac0998ce/settings/security_level', data, CFconfig)
    .then()
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

}

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running locally and on the server?

Comment: version i use is 20.2.0

Comment: on local machie its 18.16.0

Comment: with 18.16.0 on the ubuntu server i get the error "EHOSTUNREACH" so i belive its a issue with my ubuntu settings but idk what